# How do I increment a field in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a counter for payment purposes. Right now I'm testing it on paypal's cancelled state in place of an actual purchase because I don't have the credentials at the moment. Once I do I will transfer most of this code onto the actual payment success function.

Is there a way to update an int field of a firebase document by incrementing it's existing int field?

The code I have here goes into an infinite loop since it trails its own data.

```
    paymentCancelled: function(data) {
        console.log("payment cancelled")
        let db = firebase.firestore()
        db.collection("users").where("userId", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    console.log("before: " + doc.data().credits)

                    //this is where I'm having trouble
                    const creditIncrement = doc.data().credits + 100
                    var creditRef =
                        db.collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
                    return creditRef.update({
                            credits: creditIncrement
                        })
                        .then(function() {
                            console.log("Document successfully updated!");
                            return;
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            // The document probably doesn't exist.
                            console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
                        });
                })
            })
        console.log(data) //logging out contents from PayPal, unnecessary atm
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.get()` instead of `. onSnapshot()`

```
db.collection("users").where("userId", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
   .get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
       querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
           console.log("before: " + doc.data().credits)

           //this is where I'm having trouble
           const creditIncrement = doc.data().credits + 100
           var creditRef =
               db.collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
           return creditRef.update({
                   credits: creditIncrement
               })
               .then(function() {
                   console.log("Document successfully updated!");
                   return;
               })
               .catch(function(error) {
                   // The document probably doesn't exist.
                   console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
               });
       })
   })
```

`.get()` only gets data once, instead of listening to data change with `onSnapshot`

For data consistency, you might want to consider using [firestore transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

Comment: Nevermind that was definitely the mistake haha. Cheers!